# Ajax and autocomplete for fields of the same type

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete

Anybody knows how can I activate autocomplete only for the field being edited?
I have used the following example ([1](http://johnstonianera.com/demos/jQueryAutocomplete/beginning_terms.php)) which can handle one field. What i have changed is the selector (class). But of course, if i have more than one field with the same class, any change in one field is changes all the fields... The id of each field is built dynamically (input0, input1...) so i don't think i can make a reference to them. What i would like to achieve is enable the autocomplete only on the input field being currently edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*What i would like to achieve is enable the autocomplete only on the input field being currently edited.*

For this you can initialize the `autocomplete` method for that `input` which is been focussed with a check of if that elem has the class:

```
$('input[type="text"]').focus(function(){ // put focus on elements
    if($(this).hasClass('autocomplete')){ // check if the focussed one has the class autocomplete
       $(this).autocomplete({ // if yes then initialize the autocomplete for it here.
          // the options you need 
       });
    }
});
```

Comment: It worked actually, thank you! Now the problem is to disallow free text and restrict input to one of the values being returned :)